# Are choosing a satellite launching service provider or a nuclear reactor constructor political decisions?

Tags: contract-law

On what basis a government of a country chooses a satellite launch service provider or a nuclear reactor construction contractor?

Are choosing a satellite launching service provider or a nuclear reactor constructor political decisions?

Comment: This needs to be narrower; the answer is vastly different between countries. A nation with no native launch capacity (like the UK) has different incentives (price) to nations with native launch capacity (like the US), who might be more inclined to fund their own carriers over foreign companies. Particularly with sensitive payloads.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking very generally, and making the assumption that the projects will be state-owned, it is impossible to completely separate the choice of contractor from politics. At the very minimum, the method for choosing the contractor was defined by legal (and therefore political) means.

Any time the government makes a choice about how resources will be distributed, this is definitionally (in Lasswell's terms) politics.

If you're talking about a privately owned nuclear reactor then no, but any time the state is making a decision, that decision is going to be political in some way or other.